# How come when I click on the play button, it's not playing?

Tags: javascript, css

How come when I click on the play button, it's not playing? Something needs to be adjusted in the javascript I believe. Can someone help me fix it.

https://jsfiddle.net/uxbqy3uw/1/

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoeAX.png)

```
<script>
  (function iife() {
    "use strict";

    document.querySelector(".myLink1").classList.add("hide");
    var playButton = document.querySelector(".playButton1");
    playButton.addEventListener("click", firstClick);

    function firstClick() {
      document.querySelector(".myLink1").classList.remove("hide");
      var button = document.querySelector(".playButton1");
      var player = document.querySelector("#player1");
      document.querySelector('.playButton1 .initial1').style.display = 'none';
      playButton.addEventListener("click", playButtonClickHandler);
      document.querySelector(".playButton1 .play1").style.display = "inline-block";
      document.querySelector(".playButton1 .pause1").style.display = "none";
      button.classList.add("playing");
    }

    function playButtonClickHandler() {

      player.volume = 1.0;

      if (player.paused) {
        document.querySelector(".playButton1 .play1").style.display = "none";
        document.querySelector(".playButton1 .pause1").style.display = "inline-block";
        player.play();
      } else {
        document.querySelector(".playButton1 .play1").style.display = "inline-block";
        document.querySelector(".playButton1 .pause1").style.display = "none";
        player.pause();
      }
    }

  }());

</script>
```

Comment: _Welcome to Stack Overflow!_ What have you tried so far? Are you able to give any more information?  Also, be sure to check out the [S.O. Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) as well as these handy tips:[ask]

Comment: Something needs to be adjusted in the javascript I believe. Maybe the css too, I'm not sure.

Comment: Open up the dev tools (f12 key), and go to the console tab, and you'll see the error that you're getting. In this case you need to make the player variable a global variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<audio id="player1" preload="none">
```

to

```
<audio id="player" preload="none">
```

**OR**

Define "var player" in global scope and remove the "var" in "var player = document.querySelector("#player1"); "

Or move "var player = document.querySelector("#player1"); " to gloabl scope.

Or move "var player = document.querySelector("#player1") into funcntion playButtonClickHandler(){...

**Or try to control your player object by using the "document.getElementByID" built in automatic function of your browser (does not work with all browsers, especially older ones)**

Change this

```
player.volume = 1.0;
player.play();
player.pause();
```

to

```
player1.volume = 1.0;
player1.play();
player1.pause();
```

Or use the all-time-favourite to access elements of your DOM:

Change this

```
player.volume = 1.0;
player.play();
player.pause();
```

to

```
document.getElementById("player1").volume = 1.0;
document.getElementById("player1").play();
document.getElementById("player1").pause();
```

Comment: Why can't both be player1?  

<audio id="player1" preload="none">

var player = document.querySelector("#player1");

Comment: @Titus answer should explain. The problem is that the variable player variable is limited to the function firstClick. Define "var player" in global scope and remove the "var" in "var player = document.querySelector("#player1"); " and you will get to the same result. Or move "var player = document.querySelector("#player1"); " to gloabl scope. Or move "var player = document.querySelector("#player1") into funcntion playButtonClickHandler(){...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the scope of the `player` variable is limited to the `firstClick` function and you're trying to access it in the `playButtonClickHandler` function.

Just define this variable in a scope that is accessible to both these functions. Eg:

```
(function iife() {
"use strict";

    ......

    var player = document.querySelector("#player1");

    function firstClick() {
       .....
    }

    function playButtonClickHandler() {
       // "player" can be accessed from here now.
       .....
    }

}());
```

Comment: Can you show me a jsfiddle so I can better understand what you mean? https://jsfiddle.net/uxbqy3uw/1/

Comment: @htmlcssjavascript567 This is what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/9sse9onq/ line **122**

Comment: @htmlcssjavascript567 You should learn how to use the browser's dev tools to debug your code or at least look at the console to see if there are any errors.